# Upload Image Facebook SDK android error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this code and this error in Request.executeUploadPhotoRequestAsync.

What can i do thanks

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.android_logo);
Request.executeUploadPhotoRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(), bitmap, new Callback(){

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    if(response.getError() == null){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload photo is completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.getError().getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

[image]

Comment: You're not showing the actual error, but the strikethrough indicates that method is deprecated as you can also see in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/#executeUploadPhotoRequestAsync). Not sure what the other error is, but I suspect you may have imported the wrong `Callback` class.

Comment: I have this imports 

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Request.GraphUserCallback;

And no have warning of deprecations 

this is my warnings --   

"The method executeUploadPhotoRequestAsync(Session, Bitmap, Request.Callback) in the type Request is not applicable for the arguments (Session, Bitmap, 
 new Callback()"

Comment: Mouseover `Callback` and see what the fully qualified name is.